# Implementing workflow in sharepoint

Tags: 2010, workflow

When i add a document to document library , i want the document to go through a process of approval.i have only 1 level approval.

1)add doc-> mail to admin -> admin approve -> document is published.
add doc -> mail to admin -> admin reject -> document not published.

2)Also i need the mail format to be edited.
Please let me know what approach should i follow ? need links on how to do this.

3)when i acivate publishing feature , is there any workflow attached to publishing and how to edit it ?

4)can i have some workflow mechanism when a document is deleted in doc lib?

Please provide information and links to the above approach .

Comment: Please consider accepting answers to some of your other questions. People will be more willing to lend a hand if you are a good citizen of the forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some resources to get you started:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/understand-approval-workflows-in-sharepoint-2010-HA101857172.aspx

http://thorprojects.com/blog/archive/2011/10/01/writing-your-own-sharepoint-publishing-approval-workflow.aspx